# How to use Makefile to compile a single Java file?

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I have written a java file called temp.java, If I want to compile it,I will input "javac temp.java". when I change this file,I should reinput "javac temp.java", I want to write a Makefile. With Makefile, I can only input "make". So how to use Makefile to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Though GNU Make can be written to compile Java, the norm is to use build systems like Maven / Gradle to achieve the same and it gives a lot more than what you seek.

Check them out :- https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html